# How can I make my Python `set` and `frozenset` subclasses preserve their types when engaging in binary operations?

Tags: python, types, immutability, subclassing, binary-operators

I have some `set` and `frozenset` subclasses, `OCDSet` and `OCDFrozenSet` respectively. When I use them together with instances of their ancestor classes in binary operations, the ancestor classes dominate the type of the result – by which I mean, when I do something like subtract an `OCDFrozenSet` from a `frozenset`, I get a `frozenset`… but the same is true if I reverse the types in the operation (i.e. subtract a `frozenset` from an `OCDFrozenSet`.

Like so:

[image]

… what is especially counterintuitively vexing to me is the fact that using `-=` (subtract-in-place) mutates the type of the existing instance!

My knowledge of how to deal with this sort of thing comes strictly from C++, where the type of the operation is a forgone conclusion that is explicitly specified in a (likely templated) operator-overload function; in Python the type system is often much more implicit, but it isn’t so mutably unpredictable as that in-place operation would have me now believe.

So, what is the most expedient way to address this – I assume it involves overriding some double-underscored instance methods in the subclasses of interest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The in-place operations doesn't guarantee that they will update the object the in-place, it completely depends on the type of the object.

Tuple, frozenset etc are immutable types, hence it is not possible to update them in-place.

From [library reference](https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/operator.html#inplace-operators) on in-place operators:

> For immutable targets such as strings, numbers, and tuples, the updated value is computed, but not assigned back to the input variable.

Similarly the `frozenset` docs also mention the same thing [about in-place operations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.update)[[source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Objects/setobject.c#L2214)]:

> The following table lists operations available for set that do not apply to immutable instances of frozenset.

---

Now, as your `OCDFrozenSet` doesn't implements `__isub__`, it will fallback to `__sub__` method which will return the type of base class `frozenset`. The base class is used because Python has no idea about the arguments your base class would expect on the newly created `frozenset` from the `__sub__` operation.

More importantly this was a [bug in Python 2](https://bugs.python.org/issue1721812) where such operation returned the subclass instance, the fix was only [ported to Python 3](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Objects/setobject.c#L1078) though to prevent breaking existing systems.

---

To get the expected output you can provide the required methods in your subclass:

```
class OCDFrozenSet(frozenset):
    def __sub__(self, other):
        return type(self)(super().__sub__(other))

    def __rsub__(self, other):
        return type(self)(super().__rsub__(other))
```

Comment: OK wow thanks! – although (and correct me if I am wrong) isn’t the behavior I’m seeing (where the type of the instance upon which the in-place operator was used changes) mean that the updated value is actually being assigned back to the input variable, contrary to the reference? Also, your answer implies I might want implement `__isub__(…)` on mutable mutable subclasses – is this the case?

Comment: @fish2000 To input variable, yes, but it's not the same object anymore, i.e the `id()` will be different and other references to the object won't be affected either. It's just a completely new object that gets assigned to the variable. Check: https://repl.it/@ashwinichaudhary/WaryThisThing. Yes, `__isub__` is the one applicable in your case.